# Possible bug in Trend calculation with bfast/greenbrown, in RStudio

Tags: r, package, trend

I have a time-series similar to the following and I want to calculate the annual trends with the `greenbrown` package.
Everything was working perfectly a weeks ago, however, now, I get the following error :

```
mdata<-c(0.023972094, -0.008573375,  0.236974105 , 0.064463101,  0.143193305,  0.296787709 , 0.105294608, -0.024576377)
mdata_ts<-ts(mdata,frequency=1,start=c(0))

library(greenbrown)
library(bfast)

Trend(mdata_ts) # this gives the error 

Error in cut.default(cycle(y), if (sbins > 1) sbins else frequency(y) *  : 
  invalid number of intervals
```

I think the error is from `bfast` package but I am not sure. I am on the latest RStudio version on Windows 10. The `bfast` version is 1.6.1 and the `greenbrown` is the version 2.4.3.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by shitfting to the development version of package (in case anyone faces a similar issue) :

```
install_github("bfast2/strucchangeRcpp")
install_github("bfast2/bfast")
```